Having difficulty displaying a message in woocommerce at checkout
I am using the following code to make sure that a minimum of two products are purchased from a particular category, if there is less than the minimum added to the cart a message should be displayed upon checkout.
The error message I am getting is "There are some issues with the items in your cart. Please go back to the cart page and resolve these issues before checking out."
    add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'wc_min_item_required_qty' );
    function wc_min_item_required_qty() {
        $categories    = array('Noten'); // The targeted product category
        $min_item_qty  = 5; // Minimum Qty required (for each item)
        $display_error = false; // Initializing

        // Loop through cart items
        foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            $item_quantity = $cart_item['quantity']; // Cart item quantity
            $product_id    = $cart_item['product_id']; // The product ID

            // For cart items remaining to "Noten" producct category
            if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) && $item_quantity < $min_item_qty ) {
                wc_clear_notices(); // Clear all other notices

                // Add an error notice (and avoid checkout).
                wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'Please verify the minimums for your purchase. Your choice requires a minimum of %s. Your cart only contains  %s items.', $min_item_qty , $item_quantity ), 'error' );
                break; // Stop the loop
            }
        }
    }

I have disabled all plugins, changed the theme nothing seems to help.
